# Correct order of addressing

Tags: grammar, word-usage

While writing an email on behalf of 2 other people. 
Should I write.. Savin, Steve and Myself

Or

Myself, Savin and Steve.. ?

I remember reading somewhere it is always, first person, second and third.. My doubt is with the order and not in the usaage of 'Myself' or 'Me'
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Myself should come last.
For example when you are writing the mail on behalf of 2 other people you should say

> Steve, Alex and me.

Also, FYI you should use me.

Comment: Why "myself" and not "me"? Strictly speaking it should be "me" ("myself" should be used reflexively). The use of "myself" here is a kind of hyper-correction made by people who think that "me" is wrong and "I" isn't quite right. "From Steve, Alex and me" is just fine. That's the strict line on these things.

Comment: You are right. I meant 'me'. The answer has been corrected accordingly. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Margana We do not actually know whether the context requires the reflexive.  For example, the full sentence could be "I am also sending copies to Steve, Alex, and myself."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would recommend saying all three names, with yours being the last.
eg. Savin, Steve, and John.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. My response to your answer is *why*? That is not to say it is wrong, but that answers at StackExchange are expected to be definitive, providing a full explanation including appropriate references and examples. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: If the question is about the signature line of the email, then you should include your own name, not just "me"; after all, if Savin and Steve weren't involved and you were writing just for yourself, you'd sign with your name, not with "me". But if the question is about text in the body of the message, then "me" (or "I" or "myself" depending on the context) is preferable.